# I want to return only value of id and use it for another methods. Is there any way to do it in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, moodle

That is my code. Here return values are id and username in json type. But I want to return only value of id and use it for another methods. Is there any way to do it in ASP.NET?

````
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.QueryString.Add("wstoken", "49345fa96c58118326bxxxxxxxxxxx");
                wc.QueryString.Add("wsfunction", "core_user_create_users");
                wc.QueryString.Add("moodlewsrestformat", "json");
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][username]", member.uname);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][auth]", "manual");
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][password]", member.password);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][firstname]", member.fname);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][lastname]", member.lname);
                wc.QueryString.Add("users[0][email]", member.email);
                var response_data = wc.UploadValues(URI, "POST", wc.QueryString);

                var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response_data);
                return response;
            }  ```


 ***return values***
```"[{\"id\":38,\"username\":\"newuser30\"}]"```
````

Comment: You'll need to deserialize the JSON in the response to an object and extract the `id` property from it.

Comment: JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(response);
  return jsonObject["id"];,i did it that way.but it was not working

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your return json is a list. You could create a class with `username` and `id` properties and handle it cleanly.

But for a quick solution, you may use this.

```
var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(e);
        foreach(var a in k)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(a["id"]);
        }
```